# How to use some methods of Rails 4 App like a REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

I need your help please!

I have a Rails 4 app, and I need to use some methods (not all) to respond like a REST API to a mobile devices. I'm using has_secure_password model to authenticate users, and protect_from_forgery with: :reset_session to protect the app against CSRF attacks (only in post requests).

Now, I am working in a mobile app, that needs to consume some methods of my Rails 4 app, and I am a little confused about what are the changes that I need to do to allow the app respond to a device requests like a REST API.

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "respond like a REST API"?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should separate routes to be consumed by your mobile app. like

```
api/v1/<controller>/<methods>/
```

In this controller you can apply your security as oauth and have different routes that respond as json. I would that you have separate you logic to web and mobile.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # normal_routes
  ...
  namespace :api, constraints: { format: 'json' } do  
    namespace :v1 do  
      resources :posts  
    end  
  end  
end
```

you can see this gem [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape)

Answer (score 0):

It should not be too complicated. I'd probably put these mobile API routes in their own namespace to help with organization. You will usually have a separate controller for each table your mobile app is interacting with.

Below is an example of a boilerplate I use when I need a new REST controller. Hopefully it'll help you.

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    ___                      ___          _
#   / __\___  _ __  _   _    / _ \__ _ ___| |_ __ _
#  / /  / _ \| '_ \| | | |  / /_)/ _` / __| __/ _` |
# / /__| (_) | |_) | |_| | / ___/ (_| \__ \ || (_| |
# \____/\___/| .__/ \__, | \/    \__,_|___/\__\__,_|
#            |_|    |___/
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is a template controller which represents what most admin controllers look like.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Search for Camel and replace it with your camel case object (i.e. User)
# Search for snake and replace it with your snake case object (i.e. user)
# When search/replacting be sure to not include the 's'. This will handle plural/singular
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
module V1
  module Admin
    class CamelsController < ApplicationController

      # GET /admin/snakes
      def index
        if admin_can :snake_read
          render json: Camel.all, each_serializer: Adm::CamelSerializer
        end
      end

      # GET /admin/snakes/:id
      def show
        if admin_can :snake_read
          render json: @snake, serializer: Adm::CamelSerializer
        end
      end

      # POST /admin/snakes
      def create
        if admin_can :snake_create
          @snake = Camel.new(snake_params.merge!(creator: current_user))

          if @snake.save
            render json: @snake, serializer: Adm::CamelSerializer, status: :created
          else
            render json: { errors: @snake.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
        end
      end

      # GET /admin/snakes/new
      def new
        if admin_can :snake_create
          render json: Camel.new, new: true, serializer: Adm::CamelSerializer, root: "snake"
        end
      end

      # GET /admin/snakes/:id/edit
      def edit
        if admin_can :snake_update
          render json: @snake, edit: true, snake_id: params[:id], serializer: Adm::CamelSerializer, root: "snake"
        end
      end

      # PATCH /admin/snakes/:id
      def update
        if admin_can :snake_update
          if @snake.update(snake_params)
            head :no_content
          else
            render json: { errors: @snake.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /admin/snakes/:id
      def destroy
        if admin_can :snake_delete
          @snake.destroy
          head :no_content
        end
      end

      private
      def snake_params
        params.require(:snake).permit(:name).merge!(updater: current_user)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

This example assumes you are using Active Model Serializer which makes rendering JSON a lot easier. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers